# Set Zedgraph line width of existing line

Tags: c#, charts, zedgraph

Is it possible to set width of existing Zedgraph line? Most examples I saw demonstrate following method:

```
LineItem myCurve1 = myPane.AddCurve("Sine Wave", spl1, Color.Blue, SymbolType.None);
myCurve1.Line.Width = 3.0F;
```

But as I see it can be done only at moment of adding new curve. Most obvious solution is to create **List** and add all curves there to access them later. I wonder is it right way or I am at wrong track?

**UPDATE**
My situation is following. I have several line curves and list of them in *listBox*. I want to make currently selected curve bold. That is why I need access to existing curves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LineItem` has constructors that support setting the line width, so you can create the curve first and then add it to your `GraphPane`, like this:

```
LineItem myCurve1 = 
    new LineItem("Sine Wave", spl1, Color.Blue, SymbolType.None, 3.0f);
myPane.CurveList.Add(myCurve1);
```

Which approach to recommend is more a matter of taste, I think, but personally I prefer to initialize my object as much as possible before adding it to any collection.

**UPDATE** If you later on would like to access your specific curve item, simply retrieve it from `myPane.CurveList`. The objects in `CurveList` are `CurveItem`:s, so you may need to cast  to `LineItem` to modify line specific properties.

**example**

```
((LineItem)zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList[1]).Line.Width = 3.0F;
```

Comment: I hope you won't have any objections for my example in your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @user1035174 That's perfectly OK. Was my answer otherwise helpful?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to accept your answer. Yes, it strikes the target perfectly.

Comment: In which version is this constructor available? In 5.1.6.0 there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Pane in ZedGraph already have list of curves. Maybe you need redraw your pane after changing curves?